# Pip is installed, but command not found

Tags: python, pip

Pip has been on my machine for years, but recently I could not get it to work.  To fix this I ran:

```
$ sudo python get-pip.py
The directory '/Users/tomeldridge/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/tomeldridge/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-8.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.2MB 759kB/s 
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (66kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 4.3MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip, wheel
  Found existing installation: pip 7.1.2
    Uninstalling pip-7.1.2:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-7.1.2
Successfully installed pip-8.1.2 wheel-0.29.0
```

But pip still doesn't work:

```
$ pip --version
-bash: pip: command not found
```

I think I might have caused this issue messing with `$PATH`.

When I run `sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH' I get:

```
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:usr/local/bin
```

Is this correct?

Comment: `pip` (and most libs) is usually installed in user scope. Maybe you logged in another user account?

Comment: what about this command:  "python -m pip --version" ?

Comment: can you check if there is an executable called **pip** in `/usr/local/opt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is `usr/local/bin` in your path, it has to be `/usr/local/bin`.

That should do it.

You should be able to change that in the file `~/.bash_profile`.